# How to verify sui signMessage in golang？please give me a suggestion

Tags: sui

This is about the verification of sui wallet.

```
import {useWallet} from '@suiet/wallet-kit'
import * as tweetnacl from 'tweetnacl'

function App() {
  const wallet = useWallet();

  async function handleSignMsg() {
    try {
      const msg = 'Hello world!'
      // convert string to Uint8Array 
      const msgBytes = new TextEncoder().encode(msg)
      
      // call wallet's signMessage function
      const result = await wallet.signMessage({
        message: msgBytes
      })
            // verify signature with publicKey and SignedMessage (params are all included in result)
      const verifyResult = await wallet.verifySignedMessage(result, wallet.account.publicKey)
      if (!verifyResult) {
        console.log('signMessage succeed, but verify signedMessage failed')
      } else {
        console.log('signMessage succeed, and verify signedMessage succeed!')
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('signMessage failed', e)
    }
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleSignMsg}> Sign Message </button>
  )
}
```

Using the js wallet.signMessage, you can check out two pieces of data, as follows.

```
APr0hJEXc9s9FKHeubNzLkiOJd03thIJs9dnvL4M5dzEfPmzUXWrV57AM1w2k4xHdk6+R+GebKyK30Ob5oFMJQQv/sC0XycR6VEJ+JMYVNj00LdzN2XnylAv6rLwUDov/g==

messageBytes: "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh"
```

Using the wallet. VerifySignedMessage to verify these two data are correct.Because I am a golang developer, how to verify in golang. I just want to verify the result of wallet.signMessage in golang.